# Shoenfield's Absoluteness Theorem

Tags: set-theory

From wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem

"Shoenfield's theorem shows that if there is a model ZF in which a given $\Pi^1_3$  statement $\phi$ is false, then $\phi$ is also false in the constructible universe of that model."

The problem is that the only proofs I can find seem to use "a model of ZF+DC" or "a model of ZFC".

Is wikipedia right?
If so, is there a proof from just "a model of ZF" online or short enough to sketch here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wikipedia is correct in that the Shoenfield Absoluteness Theorem holds for plain ZF.

Since the proof of the theorem relies heavily on the absoluteness of well-foundedness, it is tempting to assume DC. However, since the trees that occur in the usual proof of the theorem are canonically well-ordered, DC is not necessary to prove that the well-foundedness of these trees is absolute. For a different approach, see the proof given by Barwise and Fisher in *The Shoenfield Absoluteness Lemma*. [Israel J. Math. 8 1970, 329-339, [MR278934](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=278934)]

Comment: Does it somehow follow easily from Theorem 4a in that paper?
I don't quite see it.

Comment: It actually follows from Theorem 3a, see Remark 3 which follows that theorem.